# problem with f:selectItems

Tags: jsf

I have used the following code to populate the selectbox. The code is

```
   <h:form id="myForm" prependId="false">
   <h:selectOneMenu  id ="user" value="#{customer.userName}"  >
         <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="Jose" /> 
         <f:selectItems value="#{customer.perInfoAll}" var="model" itemValue="#{model.userName}" itemLabel="#{model.userName}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu >   
   </h:form>
```

the itemLabel is showing me the correct string value, but the itemValue property for each option is showing me the list I get from the listener. Please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

<[f:selectItems](http://www.horstmann.com/corejsf/jsf-tags.html#Table4_22a)> accepts list of [SelectItem](http://myfaces.apache.org/core11/myfaces-api/apidocs/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html) which contains a value label pair.

Check the usage [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/09/objects-in-hselectonemenu.html#UsingABackingMap).

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your answer.But i'm getting a list of values from DB. When i change the value in the selectOneMenu i'm using onchange ="return alert(""+document.getElementById("form:selectOne").value);".It showing the list of objects in the alert box not the single selected value.What could be the problem? Can any body help in this issue....??

Comment: @Sarath- check the link in update and change your implementation accordingly

Comment: check the link in update and change your implementation accordingly  .... sorry i can't get you... what link i have to check..?? Could you expain me clearly..Thanks again...

Comment: @Sarath - Check this http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/09/objects-in-hselectonemenu.html#UsingABackingMap